# vlc controls and context menu flickers when I am in fullscreen mode

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz, vlc, fglrx

When I start vlc in fullscreen mode and set aspect ratio (tried only to 16:9) I cannot use context menu and controls. It is just blinking. When I do not change the aspect ratio everything works fine. I am using fglrx-updates drivers on Ubuntu 14.04. I found out on some other thread that it could be caused by compiz but still I did not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Open VLC and try *Tools*, *Ppreferences*, *Video*, *Output* and change the default to *X11*, then save and restart VLC.